# AccessDeniedException for authenticated user

Tags: spring-security

I got a server with exposed remote service and methods annotated with ROLE_ROOT. Few clients are connected to this server, authorization is done by username/password.

At some point after hours (or even minutes) of work, server suddenly returns AccessDeniedException for all clients. Clients are trying to reconnect, successfully authenticating (username/password are ok), but still getting Access Denied. Looks like user has lost his ROLE_ROOT.

After 2-3 attempts client is able to do 10-12 calls to secure method, but then again receives AccessDenied.

Does anyone has any idea what can be the problem here and where should I look?

Comment: What debugging have you done? What does the logs say?

Comment: @holmis83, debugging is tricky, because problem is not reproducible on my machine. Logs says `Access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
 at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:71)
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:203)
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
 at ...`